# Can we instantiate MFMessageComposeViewController kind of class from Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to send a message from our app extension in apple watch. Can we instantiate the MFMessageComposeViewController kind of class in Watch.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use that class on the Watch. The [MFMessageComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html) is a subclass of UIViewController, which is not available in WatchKit.

What you want to do would need to be initiated via a text input control on a WKInterfaceController, and then to send the message programmatically by passing the string from your WatchKit Extension to your iPhone app (running in the background) which then dispatches it via a web service that is connected to an SMS Gateway. It is not possible to send an SMS directly from the phone without using an MFMessageComposeViewController, so it is therefore not possible to send one directly from a third party WatchKit app without the use of such a web service.

Obviously this has cost implications, and you will want to think about how to pass this cost onto the end user, since you will be paying the gateway service bill, rather than it being charged to the end user's phone account.

Comment: For that MFMessageComposeViewController will be opened in iPhone not in watch. I want it on watch, is there any other way

Comment: I have expanded my answer to explain in more detail what I was describing.